# Fetching the file path attached to a model through a parent model relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I have a Model called application which can fetch the relation of another model called resume.  In resume model is further relation which has a $attachOne relation of a file.

```
public $attachOne = [
    'resume' => ['System\Models\File','public' => false, 'delete' => true]
    ];
```

The application has a resume attached to it though $belongsTo.

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'user' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User', 'table' => 'users'],
    'resume' => ['Acme\Job\Models\Resume']
    ];
```

I can fetch all the fields in the application model for resume, such as user_id, display_name etc but when I try to access the file attached to resume it says column not found.  Here is what I have in the application model that accesses the Resume data.

```
resume:
    label: Resume File
    type: relation
    disabled: true
    select: display_name
```

I can select all fields in that table but can't access the file attached to the resume table.  Is there any way I can access the attached system file in the application model?

Comment: And how you are accessing to that field?

Comment: In the fields.yaml I want to access it in the backend

Comment: Do you want to see the value or the document path rendered on the form, or you want to modify the file in there?

Comment: Just to see the document path to download the file.  No changes to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *[partial](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-partial)* to access to your related model attachment, something like this.

Step 1.

Setup your fields.yaml

```
resume:
  label: Resume File
  type: partial
  path: $/acme/jobs/models/resume/_resume.htm
```

2. Create a partial inside of the resume's model directory to print out the download link to the file
3. Inside of the partial you have access to `$model` variable that holds the current instance of the model if exists, for instance:

*/acme/jobs/models/resume/_resume.htm*

```
<?php if ($model->resume->resume): ?>
 <div class="form-group  text-field span-full form-pad" data-field- name="resume" id="Form-field-resume-group">
    <div>
        <a href="<?= $model->resume->resume->getPath(); ?>">Download   resume</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I wasn't sure that October could do this!